# unblock device with voice control command

Tags: lock-screens, voice-command, accessibility

I'm curious if is possible to unblock the device with voice commands. I know about the "Ok, Google" but unfortunately doesn't work with display blocked.

I'm looking for the name of an app which can be used by persons with movement disabilities (paralyzed). Can you give me some names?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it it's Known as trusted voice, it can unlock a phone simply by hearing its owner say 'OK, Google'.

'A warning advises that trusted voice unlocking is less secure than other options, but just a couple taps and you'll be able to unlock and execute commands on your secured device by simply uttering 'OK Google.''

[image]

[Source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3037733/OK-Google-Android-unlock-phone-hears-voice.html)

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Can you recommend another app which can do this job?